# MySQL join next lower value from other table

Tags: mysql, join

I've the two tables `orders`

```
id  article amount
1   1       1               
2   2       50
```

and `prices`

```
id  article min_amount  price
1   1       1           42.99   
2   2       1           5.06    
3   2       5           4.55    
4   2       10          4.3     
5   2       25          4.05    
6   2       100         2.66
```

The `prices` tables contains IDs of articles and a minimum amount you would have to buy to get a bulk discount (which would change the price for the order). I would like to join `prices` into `orders`, so that the result looks like:

```
id  article amount  price
1   1       1       42.99
2   2       50      4.05
```

The order id 2 is above the minimum (25) to get the article for 4.05€, but still below 100 at which you would get a bigger discount, so the query would to have pick the next-lower value.

I've tried this query so far

```
SELECT 
    orders.id AS id,
    orders.article,
    orders.amount,
    prices.price,
    (orders.amount - prices.min_amount) AS discount_diff
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN prices ON (prices.article = orders.article) AND (prices.min_amount <= orders.amount)
```

which gives this result

```
id  article amount  price   discount_diff
1   1       1       42.99   0
2   2       50      5.06    49
2   2       50      4.55    45
2   2       50      4.3     40
2   2       50      4.05    25
```

You can find this example on "js"fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b2bf/8

Answer (score 1):

The query you need is this:

```
SELECT orders.id AS id,
       orders.article,
       orders.amount,
       prices.price
  FROM orders
         INNER JOIN prices ON ( prices.article = orders.article
                                and prices.min_amount <= orders.amount)
         INNER JOIN ( SELECT orders.article,
                             orders.amount,
                             min(prices.price) minprince
                        FROM orders
                               INNER JOIN prices ON (prices.article = orders.article
                                                   AND prices.min_amount <= orders.amount)
                       GROUP BY orders.article,
                                orders.amount) b
                ON (     prices.article = b.article
                    AND orders.amount = b.amount
                    AND prices.price = b.minprince)
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b2bf/27